# How do i rename a file on download using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have been working on a website which will allow users to upload and download files. The file is renamed on upload and stored on my server. But when it is downloaded, it has to be renamed i.e to its original name. Presently i am using the following to do so :

```
<a href="file link" download="Original name">Download</a>
```

But the "download" attribute does not work with firefox. Any alternative using javascript or jquery ? I am using php for server side.

Edit:

Thanks for the solution using php. But that is not what i am looking for. I am using a custom file viewer using javascript. On clicking the thumbnail of the file, the viewer is displayed. An AJAX request is sent to get the link to the file. The response (the link) is used to display the file, also is added to the  tag for download. A php solution would mean a page reload on every request, which i want to avoid. So any javascript or jquery solutions ?

Answer (score 3):

On the server use `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='Original name'")`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code

```
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('newfilename.txt'));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('filename.txt'));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile('filename.txt');
```